# Are we in a case of a good pair?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Using cellular homology to Comput the homology groups of $S^n \cup_{f} D^{n+1}.$

The question is given below:

Let $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ be a map of degree $m.$ Let  $ X=S^n \cup_{f} D^{n+1}$ be the space attained from $S^n$ by attaching an $(n+1)$-cell via $f.$ Compute homology groups of $X.$

**My questions are:**

1- Are we in the case of a good pair?

2- what are the $X^n$ and the $X^{n-1}$ that should be in the LES?

3- will we use lemma 2.34 on pg.137 in AT for calculation?

Comment: Which pair should be good?

Comment: $S^{n} , D^{n+1}$ @PaulFrost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the cellular chain complex $\mathfrak C_*(X)$ of $X$ as described on p.139/140.

We have $\mathfrak C_k(X) = H_k(X^k,X^{k-1})$ which is a free abelian group with basis in one-to-one correspondence with the $k$-cells of $X$, and the boundary maps are given by the Cellular Boundary Formula on p.140.

Let us give $X$ the CW-structure with one $0$-cell, one closed $n$-cell obtained by attaching $D^n$ to the $0$-cell via the constant map on $S^{n-1}$ (thus $X^n = S^n$) and one closed $(n+1)$-cell obtained by attaching $D^{n+1}$ to $S^n$ via a map $f : S^n \to S^n$ of degree $m$.

Thus we have $\mathfrak C_k(X) = \mathbb Z$ for $k = 0,n,n+1$ and $\mathfrak C_k(X) = 0$ else. The cellular boundary formula shows that $d_{n+1}$ is multiplication by $m$. All other $d_k$ are zero. The only case where the latter is is not completely trivial is $k=1$ when $n=1$. This is treated on p.140 before the Cellular Boundary Formula.

Hence $\ker(d_n) = \mathbb Z$ and $\ker(d_k) = 0$ for $k \ne n$. We conclude
$$H_0(X) = \mathbb Z$$
$$H_n(X) = \ker (d_n)/\text{im}(d_{n+1}) = \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$$
$$H_k(X) = 0 \text{ for } k \ne 0,n$$

**Edited on request:**

I think the case $m = 0$ is not really in the focus (whence I tacitly  assumed $m > 0$). Then $H_{n+1}(X) = \ker(d_{n+1})/\text{im}(d_{n+2}) = \ker(d_{n+1})$. But $d_{n+1}$ is injective, thus its kernel is zero.

Let us have a look at $m = 0$. Then $d_{n+1} = 0$ and $H_{n+1}(X) = \mathbb Z$. Moreover, $H_n(X)  = \ker (d_n)/\text{im}(d_{n+1}) = \ker(d_n) = \mathbb Z$. In all other dimensions $k$ it is the same as for $m > 0$.

This is intuitively clear: If the attaching map is constant, then $X = S^n \vee S^{n+1}$.

Comment: why in case of $H_{n+1}(X)$ it is 0? will the answer differs if $m = 0$ in that case?

Comment: I edited my answer.